# PHP: selected value in dropdown box

Tags: php, html, html-select

I am doing an dropdown box, where I have let's say we have "option1" and "option2", the dropbox selects(marks) the "option1" and then we select the "option2", I want it to mark the "option2" in the dropdown box, but it doesn't mark it.

I'm trying to avoid to do javascript on this one, so I wonder if I can do it only on PHP.

Advices? Thanks!

Edit.
Well the problem is that i dont know how many options i have before building the dropdown menu. I get an array generated from a table in a database and make the options based on that.
Code:

```
<select name="department">
            <?php foreach(bloggModelControler::getDepartments($_SESSION['user']) as $tempDepartment){
                if(strcmp($tempDepartment, $department) == 0){
                    $selected = ".selected='selected'.";
                }else{
                    $selected = ".selected=''.";
                }
                $dropdown = "<option \"$selected\" value=\"$tempDepartment\">\"$tempDepartment\" Selected</option>";
                echo $dropdown;
}?>         
</select>
```

and $department:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['department'])){
            $department = $_POST['department'];
        }else{
            $departments = bloggModelControler::getDepartments($_SESSION['user']);
            $department = $departments[0];
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: " the dropbox selects(marks) the "option1" and then we select the "option2", I want it to mark the "option2" in the dropdown box, but it doesn't mark it." WHAT DO YOU MEAN? YOU SELECT THE VALUE BUT IT RESETS SOMEHOW? sorry for caps

Comment: yes it resets and still marks the "option1"

Comment: not clear... can you please attach a piece of HTML/PHP?

Comment: can you give me the webpage where this is happening?

Comment: @Alexein what after a page refresh?

Comment: This question is pointless without CODE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer based on updated question (included code)**

Don't put the periods inside the text variables for 'selected'.

```
if(strcmp($tempDepartment, $department) == 0){
                $selected = "selected='selected'";
            }else{
                $selected = "selected=''";
            }
```

**Previous answer**

In your PHP code that generates the HTML for the Select box, you have to specify which option is selected.

For example:

```
<select name="selectbox">
  <option <?php if ($_POST['selectbox'] == 'option1') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>option1</option>
  <option <?php if ($_POST['selectbox'] == 'option2') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>option2</option>
</selected>
```

Alternate syntax:

```
<select name="selectbox">
  <option <?= ($_POST['selectbox'] == 'option1')? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>option1</option>
  <option <?= ($_POST['selectbox'] == 'option2')? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>option2</option>
</selected>
```

Comment: I suspect your right, tho you could cut this code down with `<?=` and ternary operators ;p

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It doesn't make it much shorter, but I added the alternate syntax as you suggested as well.